# How to mount NTFS folder in another NTFS folder

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs, subst

Is there any way to redirect one NTFS folder to another? Say, to access `C:\Program Files\Modules` through `S:\Modules`? There is [`subst`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst) for mounting folders as drives, and [`diskpart`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx) and [`mountvol`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772586(WS.10).aspx) for mounting drives in folders, but I've been unable to combine the two successfully. Is it possible to achieve this?

**MORE INFO:** I found out about the `mklink` utility, but unfortunately it isn't available on Windows XP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) which is the equivalent of a symlink in NTFS.

Comment: They appear to be the same but work only for directories. NTFS also has proper symlinks since Vista.

Answer (score 2):

For easy junction & hard link creation: [HardLink ShellExt](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)